# R: gwidgets: RGtk2: gfile: multi=TRUE is not functional

Tags: r

I've noticed that multi=TRUE is not functional when used in gfile.
For example look at the following structure:

```
getfiles <- gfile(type = c("open"), filter=list("txt"=list(patterns=("*.txt"))), multi=TRUE)
```

Comment: I'm unable to find `gfile` in `RGtk2` package. What version of RGtk2 are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, there is a typo. Try using "multiple" instead of "multi" for now or grab the latest from r-forge.